# RPi no link light no networking

Tags: raspbian, networking, hardware

Just received my Raspberry Pi and the network isn't working, it's as if the network port is completely dead.  I have checked the X1 chip as others have suggested elsewhere but that hasn't made a difference.  I plan on testing the network cable today to rule out a bad cable.

The USB, audio and video all work perfectly so I don't think it's a power issue.

What else can I look at?  I'm fairly comfortable with electronics so don't mind hacking around with the hardware if necessary.

Comment: Given that you are comfortable with electronics, please tell us the voltage you measure between the +5 and GND pins of the Pi. When the network cable is connected and when it isn't. Also try to disconnect everything and use only the network cable.

Comment: @MarcoPoli 4.92 V with the network cable uplugged and 4.91/4.92 with the cable plugged in.  Would you like me update my question with these numbers?  I noticed some brief LINK activity on the Pi when I unintentionally shorted it out, dunno if that helps give any clues.

Comment: Thank pretty much rules out a low-power power source.